# ng-repeat does not work in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using `ng-repeat` to show different contents (i.e, items in an array) in different bootstrap `modal`, however something weird happens in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwR5PEOL6TEkx3sTen8a?p=preview).

I include the 'modal' in the `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example">
    {{item}}
  </button>

  <div class="modal" id="example">
    <div class="modal-content">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

So the expected result should be three buttons with three different contents (like the `<button>` 'hi' should have content `hi`, `hello` has content `hello`), however as you see in the example, all three buttons have the same associated modal content.

Any suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Comment: your data-target is the same for all three because you use id=example.
see my solve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are targeting the same ID.

Change to this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example{{$index}}">
  {{item}}
</button>

<div class="modal" id="example{{$index}}">
    <div class="modal-content">
      {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Updated plucker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2stll3MU0m31c9qSYeP?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few ways. One could involve adding a selecting function via `ng-click` - followed by setting a new model. Setting this new model allows you to remove the modal template from your `ng-repeat`, keeping your generated markup slim and manageable (this could get huge with a lot of items! - no need to repeat this `<div>` be it three or three hundred times) Observe the following example...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

    <button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-info" 
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#example" 
        ng-click="select(item)">{{ item }}</button>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="example">
    <div class="modal-content">
        {{ selected }}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello'];

    $scope.select = function(selected) {
        $scope.selected = selected
    }
});
```

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/DCcZN6Hdgquu5D0RQfNt?p=preview) - updated demo

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and question updating@scniro

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add dynamic ids to your modals, for example:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{item}}">
      {{item}}
    </button>

    <div class="modal" id="{{item}}">
        <div class="modal-content">
          {{item}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```